# I am eating "A baked salmon" or "Baked salmon"

Tags: articles

I am eating a baked salmon or I am eating baked salmon.

Why can we sometimes omit *a* and sometimes can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion is due to the noun *salmon* which is both singular and plural.

> [salmon](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/salmon) - *a large fish with silver skin and pink flesh that is used for food. Salmon live in the sea but swim up rivers to lay their eggs.* **Plural salmon.**

So, if you are talking about a single piece of a whole salmon, it takes *a* or else if it is **in general as cooked food,** it takes no article.

The OALD example "smoked salmon" tells it all.

Comment: You are also implying that we also says "I'm eating cooked fish" rather than "I'm eating a cooked fish"?

Comment: Does this theory also applys for "playing panio" and "playing a panio"?

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin *a cooked fish* is okay - http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2009/11/17/eating-a-deep-fried-fish_n_360576.html HuffingtonPost

Comment: *playing a piano* -it's a countable noun. However, **some** also favor *playing the piano* as instruments and inventions (scientific?) take the definite article.

Comment: The sheer size of a salmon makes it also very unlikely that a person would eat a whole one. Now, I can eat a herring, or maybe two, but a salmon would feed several people ;)

Comment: @oerkelens not a non-vegetarian; so have to rely more on books than a plate on my table with salmon! :)

Comment: @MaulikV: I just _love_ that double negation :) India was the first country where I saw food divided in "veg" and "non-veg" :)

Comment: I sometimes see "playing panio". Not quite often, but it normally appears as "to playing panio". I think if you google it, you might find some result.

Comment: Beware of SERPs. They are more driven by SEO than the facts!

Comment: @MaulikV About *a cooked fish*, Is both *a cooked fish* and *cooked fish* okay? - Is it like : We use "a cooked fish" when we refer to a whole fish?

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin Yes!  Applying this to both fish and pianos is correct.  "I ate (a|the) fish while playing (a|the) piano."  It doesn't have to be cooked. The fish I mean.  Pianos should always be served raw.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the size of the dish :)

If you caught a salmon, you cooked it up, and now you're eating it, you can say **"I'm eating a baked salmon"**, a fish you've caught.

Now, if you bought two pounds of salmon in the market, you're **eating baked salmon**. You can't tell if the pieces on your plate come from the same fish, and honestly, you don't care - it's *salmon meat* you're eating. You can use this expression in the prior case too (say, half of the salmon you caught was baked, the other half - smoked, now you have *smoked salmon* and *baked salmon* but *the salmon* has been split, half baked and half smoked. You can't really do the reverse: if it's not a single fish, it's fish meat, and you use the expression without the article, you're eating *salmon*, not *a salmon*.

Comment: So therefore,if the thing one is referring to is quantitative and indefinite, they use no article. For example : meat, fish meat, water, wine. Something like that?

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin: Yes, unless you specifically quantify it. You drink mineral water, but a glass of mineral water, or a bottle of mineral water. Or a serving of baked salmon.

Comment: How about *a detergent* or *a solution* (a mixture of substance in which one dissolve another)? Does *a detergent* means *a formula of detergent*? Can *detergent* be used without *a*?

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin: Yes, you can use both as 'a certain brand name detergent' meaning the product in general, encompassing all of it, 'a bottle of detergent', and 'detergent splotched on the dirty plate' without the article, meaning just a little of the detergent.

Answer (score 2):

A subtlety of English is that game or food products when treated as a commodity can omit the article: e.g. "eating fish", vs "eating a fish", or "hunting deer", vs "hunting the deer". The same applies to any object that can be treated as a homogenized 'substance' or 'collection' rather than discrete entities. Example do not sat "chopping the wood", say "chopping wood"